# MySQL selection based on more than one count

Tags: mysql

how can i list specific items from my table based on more than one count?

the Table countrylanguage table is of the form

```
CountryCode,       Language,    IsOfficial,    Percentage**
ABW                Dutch        T              5.3
AFG                Balochi      F              0.9
AFG                Dari         T              32.1
```

I have come out with this code so far but this does not give  me the right output

```
select countrycode,  Language, IsOfficial, count(*)

from 

 countrylanguage

 group by countrycode
```

and the sample output is like this:

**sample output**

Example: "Aimara'" is the official language of Bolivia and Peru', and it's also spoken in Chile but not as an official language. So the query should return the records:

```
Aimara Bolivia T
Aimara Chile   F
Aimara Peru    T
```

but for example 'Afrikaans' should not be returned, because it's spoken in two countries (Namibia and South Africa) but it's only official in one.

For each language that is official in more than one country, how can I list the name of each of the countries in which that language is spoken (indicating whether or not it is official in that country)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery with having  and in clause

```
select countrycode,  Language, IsOfficial
   where language in  
    (select  Language
    from countrylanguage
    where IsOfficial = 'T'
    having count(*)>1
    group Language ) 

order by language;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a [correlated subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/correlated-subqueries.html) will allow you to filter the languages to a list of only those that fit your criteria of being the primary language for 2 or more countries.

```
SELECT Language, CountryCode, isOfficial
FROM countrylanguage
WHERE Language IN (
    SELECT Language
    FROM countrylanguage
    WHERE isOfficial = "T"
    GROUP BY Language
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
ORDER BY Language
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!